# Working with webview and button

Tags: android, html, android-developer-api

Hello friends Its possible to view two or more html page in one webview ??
I'm working with 2 html page i.e about.html,profile.html in android studio so I set two button in activity_Main.xml i.e About and profile . I want, when user click on About button then loading `file:///android_asset//about.html` page in  and when click on profile button than loading `file:///android_asset/profile.html` page. So how can I do this task?

Answer (score 0):

Using  `webView.loadUrl` you can change the source of webView:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset//about.htm");
   }
});


button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
         webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset//profile.htm");    
   }
});
```